# iOS 15 minimized address bar issue when two of input fucused

Tags: debugging, safari, ios15

Using iOS 15.0.2 Safari, when the on-screen keyboard is dismissed, the address bar can become minimized without updating the viewport height.

here is my code.

html

```html
<body>
  <div style={{ height: '100%', background: 'red' }}>
    <div>
      <input />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

css

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
html {
  background-color: #435283;
  height: 100%;
}

input {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

reappearance

1. focus first input.
2. focus second input.
3. press 'done' on keyboard.

when i reappearance this flow the address bar was minimized.
if i focus only one input, it does not.

does it possible prevent minimizing?

expacted behaivior.

- don`t minimize address bar.

here is sample video link.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YGAsIEAjcEojOY-q8XZ4VEzKnDcVFBLd/view?usp=sharing